# upload file to server in android

Tags: android, file-upload

i want to upload a file from my android phone to server URL. but the server required login first. how can i do this to upload the file to this server URL with also login URL.
for example:
uploading url:
            http://api.someapi.net/v1/medium/14
             parameters required:   file and title

login url:
       http://api.someapi.net/v1/user/login
              parameters required:     email and password

Comment: If you want to make sure the user is logged in first, you can have the login generate and return a token. Then have the upload require (token,file,title)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the login credentials by using the code below. If the response is OK send the file to the url using the same code below with different parameters. Else do whatever you want.

```
URL siteUrl;
    try {
        siteUrl = new URL("yoururl");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) siteUrl
                .openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setDoInput(true);

        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
        String content1 = ""; 

      //Here param is the Map<String,String> which holds the value of email and password
        Set getkey = param.keySet();
        Iterator keyIter = getkey.iterator();
        String content = "";
        for (int i = 0; keyIter.hasNext(); i++) {
            Object key = keyIter.next();
            if (i != 0) {
                content += "&";
            }
            content += key + "=" + param.get(key);

        }
       //Check by printing here
        System.out.println(content);
        out.writeBytes(content.trim());
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                conn.getInputStream()));
        String line = "";
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        in.close(); 

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You need Apache's Mime4J jar file on your project (here - http://james.apache.org/download.cgi#Apache_Mime4J )

And do:

```
MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
entity.addPart("file", new InputStreamBody(file, "UPLOAD.jpg"));
request.setEntity(entity);
```

Tada!